# Performance of SQL code

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlperformance

I have SQL queries like the one below, I have many others also and at the moment we are experiencing a long time delay to run these queries as part of reports.

Does anyone know how to performance tune these to run much better and quicker this could be some program you could put the code in to and it does performance tune them, or specific things I should look to avoid doing.

I have done these in SQL developer before placing them in the reporting software. however I can not see any additional add on with on SQL developer

```
SELECT o.wh_id,
  o.bill_to_code,
  (
  CASE
    WHEN d.pick_area LIKE 'GPS%'
    THEN 'GPS'
    ELSE d.pick_area
  END)     AS pick_area,
  COUNT(*) AS Amount_of_picks
FROM t_order o
INNER JOIN t_pick_detail d
ON o.order_number = d.order_number
WHERE o.wh_id     = '~wh_id~'
AND TRUNC(d.create_date) BETWEEN dbo.usf_format_date_to_glb_locale('~WW_USERLCID~','~DateFrom~') AND dbo.usf_format_date_to_glb_locale('~WW_USERLCID~','~DateTo~')
GROUP BY o.wh_id,
  o.bill_to_code,
  (
  CASE
    WHEN d.pick_area LIKE 'GPS%'
    THEN 'GPS'
    ELSE d.pick_area
  END)
ORDER BY o.bill_to_code
;
```

Many thanks

Comment: You're using a LIKE in your group by and in your select. If you are aggregating 1000000 records how many times is this LIKE being compared? Do you have an index on `order_number` in both the `t_pick_detail` and `t_order` tables?

Comment: Questions about query performance should at least include the database structure including keys, indexes an indication of the amounts of data, and the number of rows returned from the query itself. Otherwise it's just guessing.

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com.